# Error: The response is not a valid json response. WordPress Windows server

Tags: windows, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress, json

I personally rented a Windows virtual server and installed and set up **mysql+phpadmin+IIS** and after that I started my email server and tested it and everything was ok, then I installed WordPress and set DNS records and went to upload the website, when the problems started, at first, the predefine upload volume was small, and it gave the link expiration error! By searching and updating the PHP file, the problem was solved, then it wouldn't let me install the theme correctly, I found out the Permission error, I also solved it, then now **I **can't create a page or update the existing pages****, at all and **receive** this error:

"**updating failed. the response is not a valid json response.** "

The only way I can do this is to set the **permalink** to “plain” mode. In this case, I can create a page, but when I go to update the page, the whole foundation falls apart, and for example, if the coming soon page is displayed, it turns into a blog. Also I do not see any **.htaccess** file in my WordPress main folder. can in short, please help me to solve this error. With regards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset the permalinks
   Before you try anything else, you should try resetting your permalinks to resolve the invalid JSON response error. Navigate to Settings > Permalinks in your WordPress dashboard. Then ensure that the correct permalink setting is selected and click the Save Changes button. Now try updating a page. The error should be fixed but if it still occurs, try out the solutions below.
2. Disable the Block editor and switch back to Classic editor :
   The error “Updating failed. Error message: The response is not a valid JSON response.” is overwhelmingly seen in the new Block editor called Gutenberg.

- The easiest way to resolve the updating error is by disabling Gutenberg and switching back to the Classic editor. As they say, old is Gold.
- You can install the Classic Editor plugin for this. Once you have activated the plugin, try to save your posts. You should not see any error message now.

Regards,
John